# Django trouble with generic.GenericTabularInline in admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-generic-views

I have a generic Django media model that I want to relate to a number of other models.  Everything seems to be working fine but I am unable to save new or existing objects using an inline form in the admin.  Here are the relevant models:

```
from django.db import models
from franklin.utils.content_media import *
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from franklin.core.scripts.models import Script

class Media(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    media_type = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices = media_types)
    media_file = models.CharField(max_length = 300, blank = True)
    text_value = models.CharField(max_length = 2000, blank = True)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length = 300, blank = True)
    attributes = models.CharField(max_length = 150, blank = True)
    related_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null = True, blank = True)
    template = models.ForeignKey(Script, null = True, blank = True)
    sort_order = models.IntegerField(default = 1)

class StaticContent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True)
    key = models.CharField(max_length = 200, unique = True)
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices = content_types)
    content = models.TextField(blank = True)
    media = generic.GenericRelation(Media, content_type_field='content_type', object_id_field='object_id')
```

Here is the admin code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from forms import *
from models import *
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

class MediaInline(generic.GenericTabularInline):
    model = Media
    form = MediaFormInline
    extra = 1
    verbose_name_plural = 'media'

class static_content_admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [MediaInline]

admin.site.register(StaticContent, static_content_admin)
```

Here is the offending form:

```
from models import *
from django import forms

class MediaFormInline(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Media
        fields = ('media_type', 'sort_order',)
```

The inline form is displayed properly but when I save I get the following error:

---

Django Version:     1.3 pre-alpha
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:

'NoneType' object is not iterable

Exception Location:     ...django\contrib\contenttypes\generic.py in **_*set*_**, line 217

---

The error is occurring with the **_*set*_** method of a ReverseGenericRelatedObjectsDescriptor class.  The page is sending None to the value parameter of **_*set*_**:

```
def __set__(self, instance, value):
    if instance is None:
        raise AttributeError("Manager must be accessed via instance")

    manager = self.__get__(instance)
    manager.clear()
    for obj in value:
        manager.add(obj)
```

Any help with this will be much appreciated.  If I can't solve this, I will have to go to a solution that isn't so DRY.

Comment: Can you save yourself a lot of trouble and use ForeignKey instead of generic relationships?

Comment: "Can you save yourself a lot of trouble and use ForeignKey instead of generic relationships?" - I did that originally but thought it better design to use generic relationships since the Media model was one to be used multiple times in different apps.  I've never used generic before so thought I would try it out.  With the exception of this "inline problem", it works great (tested with data inserted from the db) but this is obviously a big deal and would prevent me from moving forward with it.  Thanks for your comment.  It's nice to get a response here.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `GenericTabularInline`. See the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline).

Sample:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.admin import GenericTabularInline


class MediatInline(GenericTabularInline):
    model = Media
    extra = 1


class StaticContentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [MediaInline]
```